# Cassandra bulk insert statement does not work on specific machine

Tags: c#, cassandra, cql

I'm testing Cassandra and I made a program in C# to insert data into my database. I tested it on a machine with 16 gb ram and 8 cores. This worked perfectly fine and it inserted 1.000.000 rows without any problems, it took about 80-90 seconds.

Now I'm testing the exact same program on a different (virtual) machine with 4gb ram and 1 core. When I test it here, after about 50.000 inserts it does not insert any more (one time its 48.000, another time its 53.000).

My expectations where it would only take a lot longer but it would still finish inserting 1.000.000 rows.

Basically this is my code

```
private void bt_insert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Connect();   //
        List<Meter> userList = fillList();
        DateTime timeStamp = System.DateTime.Now;
        session.Execute("insert into meters (ID, ConnectionMeterID, ConnectionMeterRevision, PeriodStart, PeriodEnd, Volume1, Volume2, Volume3, Volume4, Volume5, Volume6, Volume7, Volume8, DataTypeID, FileID, Remarks, QualityScore, LocationID, Removed) VALUES(1,2,3,'2013-04-03 07:01:00', '2013-04-03 07:01:00', 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,'testest',3.2,11,12)");
        CloseConnection();
    }
```

I do not get any feedback what happens so I cannot post an error message. I do not think its C# related. I think its something cause by Cassandra if it thinks it will take to long to preform the task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

session.Execute is a sync action. When the execution finishes you received a response from coordinator so the code is ok. I wouldn't trash cluster with connect and disconnect on each call but keep a connection open (its actually a performance killer).
Regarding hardware and tests, we did the same thing back in the day. We tried executing crazy load tests on skinny hardware like yours. Don't expect miracles from that box since Cassandra needs at least 2 core because of all the work being done under the hood. You should be able to do development with that box but don't expect 1mil writes.

Comment: Thank you for your response, it does make sense actually.